# SparkContext parameters for spark-submit for AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am using a python script to initiate AWS clusters and use **spark-submit** to submit a python script along with other parameters.

In the python code I submit , I am using

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local', 'AppName')
```

After running for a while I get the following errors

```
16/12/14 11:26:47 WARN LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for             for 49 seconds.  Will retry shortly ... 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot renew lease for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.renewLease(FSNamesystem.java:4459)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.renewLease(NameNodeRpcServer.java:986)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.renewLease(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:652)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:632)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:238)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.renewLease(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.renewLease(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:590)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.renewLease(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:895)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:298)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

am I putting "**local**" correct parameter as the master(cluster URL) parameter for python spark-submit. My understanding is that it is for when you run spark local on your system.

Also I am not sure if this error is related to this issue.

Comment: It seems issue with `HDFS`. check available disk space and bring up **NN** from `safe mode`.

Comment: any update on it ?

Comment: I was wrongly specifying the spark context. Since I was giving parameters in the script and in shell it seems like it was being over ridden. I fixed that.